# MLFLow recipe - Ingest from HDFS

Tags: mlflow

I have a HDFS directory containing a bunch of parquet files.

These files need to be ingested for training & I am using MLFlow recipes to build the workflow.

I have a custom loader method that reads data from given HDFS location, reads the files using fsspec package and returns a data-frame.

I have below ingest config part of recipe.yaml,

```
    location: "<HDFS location with parquet files>"
    using: "parquet"
    loader_method: load_files_as_dataframe
```

All I need is to pass location as parameter to load_files_as_dataframe method without MLFlow doing anything (like validation of path, file format etc) and let the custom method take care of everything.

Is this possible ?.